# Django Channels - Handshaking & Connect, but websocket.connect function is not executed

Tags: websocket, connection, django-channels

I'm working on a django project with channels involved in different apps. The first app (receiving data from a sensor) has it's own consumer and routing, as well as the second one (updates a list of logged in users).

Within the first app everything works fine.

In the second app the handshake is completed and the connection is established, but the function, that is linked to `websocket.receive` is not executed.

```py
from channels.routing import route, route_class
from channels.staticfiles import StaticFilesConsumer
from users.consumer import ws_connect, ws_disconnect

channel_routing = [
    route('websocket.connect', ws_connect, path=r'^/users/lobby/'),
    ...
]
```

and the `ws_connect`

```py
import json
from channels import Group
from channels.handler import AsgiHandler
from channels.auth import channel_session_user,
    channel_session_user_from_http, channel_session

@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_connect(message):
    print('test')
```

The `print('test')` of `ws_connect` is never executed. Additionally it even doesn't matter what url ending I'm using in javascript.

```js
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/users/lobby/');

ws.onopen = function() {
  console.log('connect');
  ws.send('connect');
}
```

The `ws` of the javascript will connect with `.../users/lobby/` or `.../lobby/` of `.../users/`.

Thanks for any hints on this!

Answer (score 0):

Since i apparently need 50 reputation to make a comment i'm just gonna make an answer instead even tho i am not sure this is the solution for you.

I had the same exact problem when copying parts of the the github multichat project made by the guy whom made channels.

My issue was apparently that i hade miss spelled the routing with a slight misstake and therefor it didn't call the correct function i had setup for that routing.

So my advice is that you trippel check the routing everywhere to see if you've messed up. I personally only checked my APP routing when error checking but it was in my project folder i had messed upp my routing.

Another thing that might be cauzing this issue is that you only have a routing in your app, but not in the main folder. In that case you need to include the other app routing with the path you want for it just like a view:

```
from channels import include


channel_routing = [
        include("crypto_chat.routing.websocket_routing", path=r"^/chat/stream/$"),
        include("crypto_chat.routing.chat_routing"),
]
```

App routing:

```
from channels import route
from .consumers import  ws_connect, ws_receive, ws_disconnect, user_offline, user_online, chat_send

websocket_routing = [
    route("websocket.connect", ws_connect),
    route("websocket.receive", ws_receive),
    route("websocket.disconnect", ws_disconnect),
]

chat_routing = [
    route("chat.receive", chat_send, command="^send$"),
    route("chat.receive", user_online, command="^online$"),
    route("chat.receive",user_offline, command="^offline$"),
]
```

If that doesnt help then i suggest you head over to the github channel page for examples and compare the two. Keep in mind tho that the project is probably made from an erlier version of channels (and maybe django aswell).

https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels-examples

Hope it helps and as i said i would have made a comment but i can't since of my rep apparently...